# Extracting information from certificate for web3signer

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm looking to create a known_host file from a certificate.

The file contents use the format:

```
<hostame>:<port> <hex-string>

<hostname> is the server hostname
<port> is the port used for communication
<hex-string> is the SHA-256 fingerprint of the server’s certificate.
```

For example

```
localhost:8200 7C:B3:3E:F9:98:43:5E:62:69:9F:A9:9D:41:14:03:BA:83:24:AC:04:CE:BD:92:49:1B:8D:B2:A4:86:39:4C:BB
```

Currently I can run

```
openssl x509 -noout -in <path/to/certificate> -fingerprint -sha256
sha256 Fingerprint:7C:B3:3E:F9:98:43:5E:62:69:9F:A9:9D:41:14:03:BA:83:24:AC:04:CE:BD:92:49:1B:8D:B2:A4:86:39:4C:BB
```

Is there a way to leverage openssl to get the desired outcome?